# Any ABBYY Finereader users here?

Tags: applications, ocr

I am trying to scan old source code in BASIC and other languages like Pascal. I have tried a couple of OCR products with mixed results. The big problem is they don't treat spaces as important and run multiple spaces together into one.

I had a short email exchange with ABBYY's tech, who said you can select BASIC as the language. I'm on the demo version and it doesn't have that option, and when I look at the mac online help I don't see it either.

Does anyone out there use Finereader on the Mac and might comment?

Comment: Might be easier to clarify this directly with the person at ABBYY you have been in contacct already.

Comment: Or to look at https://pdf.abbyy.com/finereader-pdf-for-mac/specifications/ :-)

Comment: I have been in contact, but they will not respond to people with the demo version and $89 is a lot to try scanning a page to see if it works.

Comment: Well, it says on page that Basic is supported

Comment: Sure, but does it *actually work*? I don't think it's unreasonable to see if any SE users have a copy and might comment.